# Question about Python NumPy 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with size `[49152, 3]`, I want to append another array with same size `[49152, 3]` as a new row to become `[2, 49152, 3]`. May I know the way to do this?
All of these are RGB image pixel values from 192x256 resolution images.

Comment: With what data should the new array be filled? It is twice as big as the first one.

Comment: Im sorry that my question is wrong, i have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insert` function of `numpy` in Python.

```
x = np.array([49152, 3])    
X = np.insert(x, 0, 2)
```

x is the original array to append to
0 is the index where you need to append
2 is what needs to be appended.

Comment: Im sorry that my question is wrong, i have updated it.

Comment: So do you want to make it a 2 dimensional np array?

Comment: I want to make it become the NumPy array size with [2, 49152, 3]

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to use [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(49152, 3)
>>> b = np.random.rand(49152, 3)

>>> np.stack([a, b]).shape
(2, 49152, 3)
```

You can provide a *list* (or *tuple*) of arrays of same shape, and `np.stack` will stack them on a newly created axis (by default on the first: `axis=0`).

Comment: May I know how to store all these arrays in a variable under a for loop, it shows ** ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape **
x_train = np.empty([49152, 3])

print('Get train images pixels: ')
i = 0

for train_image in train_images_list:
  each_image = Image.open(train_image)
  pixels = np.array(each_image.getdata())
  x_train = np.stack([x_train, pixels])

  i = i + 1
  print(i,'/48300')

Comment: Make sure `a` and `b` have the same shape, do they?

Comment: Don't do this in a loop.  Do the `stack` at the end on the whole list of arrays.

Comment: Initially, I have created an empty NumPy array with shape [49152, 3]. After the first loop, it can store the array with the same shape, but due to the shape is [2, 49152, 3] for the second time, it shows the wrong shape. 
How can it be fixed? I just want to declare one empty NumPy array and store all array with shape [49152, 3]. I don't want to use a list and convert afterward, it cost a lot of time because the total shape is in the shape [161, 49152, 3].

Comment: If you already have that third dimension, you will need to use `np.concatenate` instead of `np.stack` to avoid creating a new axis.